# Finding the equivelent capacitance of the circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, capacitance, electromagnetic, capacitive

Finding the equivelent capacitance of:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiTnrf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think that it should be:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{C_3}+\frac{1}{C_4}}$$

Am I right?

Comment: @Oldfart I'm sorry, now it has.

Comment: Don't forget that capacitors are not resistors.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I know that.

Comment: @asd Then why are you equivalating the whole circuit as if they were?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think that I didn't I did use the parallel and series capacitor equations (if I used them the right way of course)

Comment: That's what I was trying to delicately point out: you are not using them right. Parallel capacitors add up, series capacitors are treated like parallel resistors are.

Comment: As this ends up being a two object network, product over sum would also work: [(C1+C2) * (C3+C4)] / (C1 + C2 + C3 + C4)

Comment: If you are talking about the capacitance of the nodes across the voltage source then the capacitance is, in effect, infinite (due to the voltage source being present).